# No Anchor option for Visual Studio TabControl?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, tabpage

Originally I had a form working with anchoring.  Then I decided I wanted to have multiple tabs, so I added the TabControl, then copied labels, textboxes, and a treeview to inside the first TabPage. Now, when I resize the form, the TabControl doesn't resize.

For example, I have anchors: Left, Top, Right on my Text Field "Environment".
Why is there no "Anchor" property on the TabPage itself?  How do I make the tab page and fields resize when the form is resized?

[image]

Comment: The `TabControl` itself has anchors, not the `TabPage`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov - Thanks, I didn't realize there was a property window for each.  Why not put in answer instead of comment?